# Installing Haskell on Ubuntu 14.04 for Web Development

Tags: linux, ubuntu, haskell

How do I get myself setup using Haskell on Ubuntu 14.04 for Web Development?

I have read a bunch of tutorials and nothing is working. I get half-way down the tutorial and something in the terminal just fails miserably resulting in me having to spend hours searching for a solution just to get back to where I left off.

Is there just some binaries I could use to install everything on Linux? I can't find it in the Software Center.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/):

```
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

For web development, I use the method described in [Yesod quick start](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), only I do it in a [cabal sandbox](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html)

```
cabal update
cabal sandbox init
cabal install happy alex yesod-platform yesod-bin --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals
export PATH=.cabal-sandbox/bin/:$PATH
yesod devel
```

Comment: I got up to the point where I do `cabal sandbox init` and it failed. As usual. Is there another way to just setup Haskell without using some sandbox or.. I just want to install the language/sdk or whatever and use a text editor to write code.

Comment: @Aeron "it failed" is not very descriptive. Installing the haskell platform is the absolute easiest way to get haskell. If you want, you can try to build [ghc](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) from source or find binaries for your system. The easiest thing to do is probably post your error as a question on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I have a habit of forgetting to finish what I was saying before pressing post. When it fails, it says cabal sandbox init - command not found. I have already downloaded and installed the platform hiwever whwnever I try to run any commands it says command not found.

Comment: that means that cabal either isn't installed or is not in your PATH variable. you can always install cabal like this: "apt-get install cabal-install"

Comment: type "which cabal" to see if its in the current path. (probably not)

Comment: can it find `cabal` at all or just not the sandbox ? I think the version of cabal coming with the haskell platform is 1.16 which doesn't have sandbox. You need to upgrade cabal `cabal uptate; cabal install cabal-install` to get 1.18 wich have sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is installing yesod via Nix Package Manager.

Install nix (http://nixos.org/nix/download.html):

```
bash <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install)
```

Install yesod and a few tools:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.haskellPackages.{hjsmin,persistentSqlite,yesod,yesodBin,yesodStatic,cabalInstall,ghc}
```

Create a skeleton project:

```
yesod init
```

Then start it:

```
ghost@ubuntu:~/foo$ yesod devel
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring foo-0.0.0...
Forcing recompile for ./Model.hs because of config/models
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of config/routes
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of messages/en.msg
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout.hamlet
Forcing recompile for ./Handler/Home.hs because of templates/homepage.hamlet
Forcing recompile for ./Handler/Home.hs because of templates/homepage.julius
Forcing recompile for ./Handler/Home.hs because of templates/homepage.lucius
Rebuilding application... (using cabal)
Starting development server...
Starting devel application
Devel application launched: http://localhost:3000
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "user"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"ident" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"password" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_user" UNIQUE ("ident"))
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "email"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"email" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"user" INTEGER NULL REFERENCES "user","verkey" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_email" UNIQUE ("email"))
20/Jul/2014:13:19:30 +0300 [Debug#SQL] "CREATE TABLE \"user\"(\"id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\"ident\" VARCHAR NOT NULL,\"password\" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT \"unique_user\" UNIQUE (\"ident\"))" [] @(persistent-1.3.1.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Raw ./Database/Persist/Sql/Raw.hs:38:5)
20/Jul/2014:13:19:30 +0300 [Debug#SQL] "CREATE TABLE \"email\"(\"id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\"email\" VARCHAR NOT NULL,\"user\" INTEGER NULL REFERENCES \"user\",\"verkey\" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT \"unique_email\" UNIQUE (\"email\"))" [] @(persistent-1.3.1.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Raw ./Database/Persist/Sql/Raw.hs:38:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have old Cabal (version 1.16.*), which is included into Ubuntu 14.04. You should upgrade Cabal. I can see the following options for you:

1) Upgrade the whole Ubuntu to 14.10. You will get Cabal version 1.20.*.

2) If you are not ready for full OS upgrade, upgrade only Cabal:

2.1) Temporarily add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
```

2.2) Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
```

2.3) Remove the line added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` in step 2.1.

2.4) Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2.5) Check that your cabal is upgraded:

```
cabal --version
```

You should get:

```
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library
```